# Extract personal information about a person from a list of documents and summarize it

Tags: nlp, nltk

I need to extract personal information about a person from a list of documents and summarize it to the user. If there are 2 people with the same name, the correct person should be identified. If the person has a nickname, that also needs to be identified. The input to the program can be the name of the person, address, organization name etc. I have extracted named entities like person, org, location etc from the text using NLTK library. The output after extracting the named entities is mentioned below,

[('Michael', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Joseph', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), ('Jackson', 'NNP', 'I-PERSON'), ('was', 'VBD', 'O'), ('born', 'VBN', 'O'), ('in', 'IN', 'O'), ('Gary', 'NNP', 'B-GPE'), (',', ',', 'O'), ('Indiana', 'NNP', 'B-GPE')....

Now, I want to extract relationships between those entities.

Answer (score 1):

Your task is really related to NLP information extraction. Take a look here to get an overview will be better. [Stanford Information extraction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlmNvfyVy_4).

Also, if there are duplicate names, a technique named Entity linking could address it.

The title of the documents could also help as a condition when you want to output more exact result.

This is an example of Information extraction in NLP.
Hope this helps!

[image]